# Get Video Signal of Security Cam and show it

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, camera, raspberry-pi

I have an security cam which sends the video stream over 2,4 GHz to a receiver. I now want to know, if it's possible to receive this signal on iPhone and show the video stream. As WiFi is also sending on 2,4 GHz, the iPhone should be able to receive that signal. Or not?

Security Cam: http://www.jay-tech.de/jaytech/servlet/frontend/content.html?articleOID=d583e45:-495a2735:120c7c04348:446c&keywordOID=d583e45:946c233:1182e6a651d:e4e.
My iPhone is a iPhone 5s on iOS 8.1

If it's not possible over iPhone, is it may possible to catch the signal with any other device? I have this devices which I could use:
Raspberry PI, old WiFi USB Stick, Arduino Uno and a buch of cables for TV/Audio/Video etc

Thanks iComputerfreak

Sorry for my bad English, I'm German ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. To receive the signal, you'd need some dedicated hardware to receive the signal and encode it into a format that the iPhone could understand. It's not possible to arbitrarily capture wireless signals on a particular frequency and decode them in software - not on an iPhone, anyway.

Your best solution would be to look for some external hardware which operates on the same frequency, and can encode the video signal over a wifi network - I'd be surprised if such a device doesn't exist, though it may not be cheap. The iPhone can then simply receive the encoded video via wifi and use it like any other video stream.